# calling Java functions without any reference

Tags: java, function, jsp

I have a java class contain some functions.
If i import class in jsp page, is there any way to access them without class reference and object reference.

Comment: Are the methods static or instance?

Comment: Custom tags or custom EL functions (static only by nature).

Answer (score 1):

Call method without creating `Object`,

If method is `public` and `static` you can use `YourClass.method()`

As stated in your question you have imported the class,

You can use `static` import after making your method `public static`

```
<%@ page import="static package.YourClass.methodName"%>
```

or to access all `static` stuff,

```
<%@ page import="static package.YourClass.*"%>
```

Comment: I didn't want use any reference either class or object
i want to use them directly like we use in php
is there any ways

Comment: but is there any way to include them with class only,because
it is difficult to include all method like you said

Comment: @rak - No there isn't.  Java + JSP doesn't have global functions like PHP's.  This (TAsk's answer) is as close as you will get.

Comment: In java either u need class name or instance name, Without that it can't be accessible in java.